# what is poco in mvvm?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Here, I am using MVVM in WPF and I read that it contains poco. I also read that is contains vanilla property.

```
    public class AccountCategory : IDataErrorInfo, IValidable
    {
        #region State Properties

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public AccountCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
        public bool Builtin { get; set; }

    }
```

What is that? Is it Microsoft entity frame work for linq to sql? Why?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object

Comment: hey it is Microsoft entity frame work for linq to sql?

Comment: It's just a simple class.  A Plain Old CLR Object.  Nothing fancy at all.

Comment: so it is not Microsoft entity frame work for linq to sql.ok

Comment: There is no such think as "entity framework for linq to Sql". "entity framework" and "linq to Sql" are two separate ORMs

Comment: Vanilla property is an opposite of dependency property I guess? Former is owned and encapsulated in the class, latter is contained in dictionary somewhere deep inside of DependencyObject. In this context, POCO may mean that class is not derived from specific class (DependencyObject or EntityObject?) and not decorated with specific attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess they are referring to Entity Framework. POCO means "Plain old CLR object". Some ORMs require entities to inherit from a specific base class, use special attributes on classes and properties, and other methods in order to map an object to the database.

Linq To SQL requires you to use classes generated by the designer, which uses attributes and things like that.

The "POCO" approach refers to the fact that an ORM can map any object, not requiring special attributes or base types. Therefore, I would assume they are talking about EF since 4+ supports POCO mapping.

Comment: @hitech It's called a CLR object since there is no difference between objects declared in c#, f#, vb.net, etc. and they all run on the Common Language Runtime